# bash: C:Usersha_haAnaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, git-bash

I am using Windows. Whenever I launch git bash I get the following error message

```
bash: C:Usersha_haAnaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory
```

I think some of the path separators are `\` instead of `/` i.e. the path is supposed to be `C:/Users/ha_ha/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh:` which is why git bash is not able to find the shell script. How and where can I fix this?

Comment: So have you checked the path variable?

Comment: Yes I have. The PATH variable does not have C:Usersha_haAnaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh

Comment: That path isn't valid. I am guessing the user profile is `sha_ha` can you confirm?